# Python Tkinter - How can you use a value from one function to another?

Tags: function, class, tkinter

I am learning Python and Tkinter on my own and I have some questions regarding this code that I am writing. 
I am trying to get the program to execute two functions that are part of a class.
So when I try to execute the below code tkinter executes the first function but does not execute function 2 and I don't understand why.
Can someone please help me with this. 
And in function2 the value of j needs to equal the value of j from function1.
Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
myapp=Tk()
myapp.geometry('1100x700+100+50')
myapp.title('List Generator')

input1=IntVar()
input2=IntVar()

class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        text1=input1.get()
        text2=input2.get()
        ex1=float(text1)
        ex2=float(text2)
        totbtu=float(ex1*ex2)
        realbtu=totbtu+(totbtu*0.15)
        j= float(totbtu + 100)
        Label(myapp, text=totbtu).place(x=600,y=20)
        Label(myapp, text=realbtu).place(x=600,y=60)
        Label(myapp, text=j).place(x=600,y=100)

    def function2(self):
        h=j+33
        Label(myapp, text=h).place(x=600,y=140)

label1 = Label(myapp, text='Enter Area').place(x=10,y=10)
area_entry=Entry(myapp,textvariable=input1 ).place(x=140,y=10)
label11 = Label(myapp,text='SQ FT',).place(x=270,y=10)

label2 = Label(myapp, text='Enter Load').place(x=10,y=35)
area_entry=Entry(myapp,textvariable=input2 ).place(x=140,y=35)
label22 = Label(myapp,text="BTU's/SQ FT",).place(x=270,y=35)

button1 = Button(myapp, text = 'Generate',padx=5,pady=5,command=Myclass).place(x=10,y=70)

myapp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to call 2 functions with one button command **and** you also need to use one value in both functions (I'm assuming).

Take a look at my solution:

```
from Tkinter import *
myapp=Tk()
myapp.geometry('1100x700+100+50')
myapp.title('List Generator')

input1=IntVar()
input2=IntVar()
j = 0 #needed for the value to be referenced in both function1 and function2
def function1():
   global j
   text1=input1.get()
   text2=input2.get()
   ex1=float(text1)
   ex2=float(text2)
   totbtu=float(ex1*ex2)
   realbtu=totbtu+(totbtu*0.15)
   j= float(totbtu + 100)
   Label(myapp, text=totbtu).place(x=600,y=20)
   Label(myapp, text=realbtu).place(x=600,y=60)
   Label(myapp, text=j).place(x=600,y=100)
   print(j)

def function2():
   global j
   h=j+33
   Label(myapp, text=h).place(x=600,y=140)
   print(j)

def wombocombo():
   function1()
   function2()
label1 = Label(myapp, text='Enter Area').place(x=10,y=10)
area_entry=Entry(myapp,textvariable=input1 ).place(x=140,y=10)
label11 = Label(myapp,text='SQ FT',).place(x=270,y=10)
label2 = Label(myapp, text='Enter Load').place(x=10,y=35)
area_entry=Entry(myapp,textvariable=input2 ).place(x=140,y=35)
label22 = Label(myapp,text="BTU's/SQ FT",).place(x=270,y=35)

button1 = Button(myapp, text = 'Generate',padx=5,pady=5,command=wombocombo).place(x=10,y=70)

myapp.mainloop()
```

When you dictate a function to be called when a button is pressed, you use `command=myFunction` myFunction is a function, not a class. And as such, when a class like `Myclass` is the command instead of a function, problems will occur.

To execute 2 functions with 1 command, simply combine both functions into 1. If you take a look at the `wombocombo` function, it will call both `function1` and `function2`, hitting 2 birds with 1 stone.

---

As for sharing a variable between both functions, I always find it easiest to go broader one step on the scope ladder and add my variable there.

In this example, we needed the same j variable in both `function1` and `function2`. Going broader in scope, we define j in a place that both `function1` and `function2` can access.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Gunner. I just started learning to code in python so this is great help.

Comment: Hi Gunner, I still have a problem with this code as in function2 I want to use the value of j from function1.

Comment: @PeterS Hi, thanks for letting me know. I'm not sure what I was thinking before, BUT j should be the same in both functions. I added 2 more lines, one on the first line of each function that tells the program "In this function, use the global j variable, dont use the local". The edits I made should help! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Gunner, it works. Thank you very much. This is great. Every time I click the "generate" button it prints the value of j in Idle. Is that ok?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to write this code and not use global variables as I will have quite a few of them.Thanks

Comment: @PeterS As far as this example goes, Im fairly certain globals are the only way to go. You need a variable that extends its scope to both functions and thats what a global does. If there is another way, I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Gunner.